# htaccess deny from lasts nine numbers

Tags: .htaccess

I have a little question,

how can I use `deny from` on my `.htaccess` to deny connection from:

`111.111.111.11*` ?

I tried to use `*` and `*.*` but didn't work.

I would deny all number from

```
111.111.111.110
```

to

```
111.111.111.119
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you simply try `deny from 111.111.111.11` ?

Comment: `111.111.111.11(\d{1})`..?

Comment: @JustinIurman That shouldn't work, as this might be an explicit IP. It would only work with a missing dot at the end like `111.111.111` that would block everything from the last /24.

Comment: Normally, one would use to block a subnet like a /28 or /29. As the range `111.111.111.110` to `111.111.111.119` doesn't represent one, it would not work. For example, `deny from 111.111.111.113/28` would block the /28 subnet from `111.111.111.113` to `111.111.111.126`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to use `SetEnvIf`, like so:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^111\.111\.111\.11[0-9]$ GetOut=1

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=GetOut
```

See [the docs for SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) and [a document about Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) with a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

`Deny from` doesn't take regex but you can use `mod_rewrite` to that effect:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 111\.111\.111\.11[0-9]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```